# Dropzone File Upload Rails - Getting Started

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dropzone.js

This is probably a super dumb question but I'm trying to get Dropzone Image Upload rails gem working and I'm not sure what to do next.
https://github.com/ncuesta/dropzonejs-rails

I've followed the readme. I installed the gem

```
gem 'dropzonejs-rails'
```

included the JS

```
//= require dropzone
```

and included the CSS

```
/*
  *= require dropzone/dropzone
*/
```

What now? Don't I have to give a html element an ID or something? Do I have to specify an upload url? Do I need a form? Do I need a model and controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read and follow the instructions on [this page](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) too. All the rails gem does is make the asset files available.

Comment: I am trying to upload more than 5 images on Amazone s3 at a time and my AJAX code is in the success block which updates a div with uploaded files. What happens if I select 4 images and upload, it is working. But if I upload more than 4 images, it's uploading but not getting the callback in success block. Do you know why?